# Mave version management

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, maven

I want to manage version of my maven project automatically.

We have multiple multi Module project running on aws.
Projects are using dependency of other project.

Please share if some how we can achieve this.

We are tiring some maven plugin, but its can manage the versions within the same projects.

Idea is, if I push a new version of a project and dependency should be updated in other project i.e we should not update dependency in project pom manually.

Example : Project A have modules A.a and A.b and project B have dependency on A.a jar
When a new version of project a is deployed project B should automatically use latest version of project A.

Answer (score 0):

Run `versions:use-latest-versions` on project B before the build.

Then B has the latest versions of the dependencies.

If you want to, you can automate that in your Jenkins/GitLabCI/whatever.